Autofac Generics Registration
I have one c# project which is using libraries from Ardalis Specification , I need to work with two different DbContext.
So, from Autofac side I need to register generics which will implement IRepository, IReadRepository .With my current code when I should use repository related to one SapScriptDbContext it is throwing me an error "System.ArgumentException: Cannot create a DbSet for 'CooisHeader' because this type is not included in the model for the context."
public class AppEfRepository<T> : RepositoryBase<T>,IReadRepository<T>,IRepository<T> where T : class,IAggregateRoot
{
    public AppEfRepository(ApplicationDbContext context):base(context)
    {
        
    }
}

public class SapScriptDbContext : DbContext
{
    public SapScriptDbContext(DbContextOptions<SapScriptDbContext> options):base(options)
    {
        
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<CooisHeader>().ToTable("CooisHeader");
        modelBuilder.Entity<CooisComponent>().ToTable(nameof(CooisComponent));

    }

    public DbSet<CooisHeader> CooisHeader => Set<CooisHeader>();
    public DbSet<CooisComponent> CooisComponent => Set<CooisComponent>();
}

public class AutofacInfrastructureModule : Module
{
    private readonly List<Assembly> _assemblies = new List<Assembly>();
    public AutofacInfrastructureModule(Assembly? callingAssembly = null)
    {
        AddToAssembliesifNotNull(callingAssembly);
    }

    private void AddToAssembliesifNotNull(Assembly callingAssembly)
    {
        if (callingAssembly != null)
        {
            _assemblies.Add(callingAssembly);
        }
    }

    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        LoadAssemblies();
        RegisterEf(builder);
    }

    private void LoadAssemblies()
    {
        var coreAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(CooisHeader));
        var appCore = Assembly.GetAssembly((typeof(Cut)));
        var infrastructureAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(AutofacInfrastructureModule));
        AddToAssembliesifNotNull(coreAssembly);
        AddToAssembliesifNotNull(appCore);
        AddToAssembliesifNotNull(infrastructureAssembly);
    }

    private void RegisterEf(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(SapScriptEfRepository<>))
            .As(typeof(IRepository<>))
            .As(typeof(IReadRepository<>))
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        //If I comment this bellow app is working and no error
        builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(AppEfRepository<>))
            .As(typeof(IRepository<>))
            .As(typeof(IReadRepository<>))
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

    }
}

From Program.cs
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SapScriptConnection");
         var defaultConnectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
           builder.Services.AddDbContext<SapScriptDbContext>(cfg => cfg.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
           builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(cfg => cfg.UseSqlServer(defaultConnectionString));

I'm trying to resolve DI with autofac where I can use generic repository for multiple dbcontexts
UPDATE
StackTrace:
System.ArgumentException: Cannot create a DbSet for 'CooisHeader' because this type is not included in the model for the context.
at Cutter.Pages.IndexModel.OnGetDataAsync(String pro) in C:\Users\boksand-adm\source\repos\Cutter\Cutter\Pages\Index.cshtml.cs:line 95
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.ExecutorFactory.GenericTaskHandlerMethod.Convert[T](Object taskAsObject)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.ExecutorFactory.GenericTaskHandlerMethod.Execute(Object receiver, Object[] arguments)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeHandlerMethodAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeNextPageFilterAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Rethrow(PageHandlerExecutedContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)
I had also tried with Keyed to manage it, but still same issue.
Only what I found as solution is to RegisterType for each entity, to be honest it is something what I do not like and prefer to do it.
This at the moment it works:
builder.RegisterType<SapScriptEfRepository<CooisHeader>>().As<IRepository<CooisHeader>>();
builder.RegisterType<SapScriptEfRepository<CooisComponent>>().As<IRepository<CooisComponent>>();
builder.RegisterType<AppEfRepository<Cut>>().As<IRepository<Cut>>();


You should probably include the whole exception with the stack trace and all. The way it reads, it has nothing to do with Autofac and everything to do with EF. But there's no way to tell because there's not enough info.

@TravisIllig please check my updated question

Given Autofac isn't in the stack trace I can't personally help - the stack trace indicates where the error is (C:\Users\boksand-adm\source\repos\Cutter\Cutter\Pages\Index.cshtml.cs:line 95) which should help you try to repro it in a simpler test on your system. The message sounds like something from EF, indicating you may not have all the EF stuff wired up right. But I don't use EF or "Ardalis Specification" or Razor Pages, so I can't provide an answer here based on the available info.
